# Publishing one sheet from a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet which contains multiple individual sheets.  In the upper right corner, the blue "Share" button shows "Anyone on the internet with the link can open it".  View only.

I published one of individual sheets to the web and provided the link to a friend via Gmail.  they were able to view the published document without issue; however, if I then forward this same email to another friend and they click the link, they get the following message:

You need permission to access this published document.

My question is why can't my friend open the published sheet?

Thanks!